# Summation of Uncorrelated Random Variables

Tags: statistics, summation, correlation

I saw this in slides for a economics class but I cannot see how to prove it using this hint - they seem to all cancel out regardless of how I distribute the summation:

$ \frac{1}{N} \Sigma ab = \frac{1}{N} \Sigma a \frac{1}{N} \Sigma b = \bar a \bar b $

Prove by writing:
$ a = \bar a + a - \bar a $,
$ b = \bar b + b - \bar b $

[screenshot of slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ0rH.png)

Comment: I think it should be $E(ab) = E(a) \times E(b)$, which is the definition of zero correlation. Having the same expected value does not mean LHS of the equation will always equal to RHS of the equation.

Comment: I suggest you ignore that "useful factoid": It is unclear at best and incorrect at worst.  No limits are given on the sum; no definition of "uncorrelated on a sample" is given; no relation to random variables and/or probability is made.

Comment: If you define two _sequences_ $\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ and $\{b_1, ..., b_n\}$ to be "uncorrelated" if $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-\overline{a})(b_i-\overline{b})=0$, where $\overline{a} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ and $\overline{b} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n b_i$, then you can prove the desired equality.  However, it is misleading to suggest this definition extends to random variables $A_i(\omega)$ and $B_i(\omega)$ because the sample path property $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (A_i(\omega) - \overline{A})(B_i(\omega)-\overline{B})=0$ is unlikely to hold for all outcomes $\omega$.